# How to kill a Robocopy batch script via Taskkill?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, taskkill

I started a batch script that activates Robocopy to copy some really big folder from some source to a destination.

When I run the script I can see the cmd with Robocopy working.

**What I want to know is** if there is a way for me to kill that Robocopy task via taskkill? Say by another batch script.

Comment: taskkill /F /IM robocopy.exe

Comment: You'd need to close the `cmd.exe` process in which the robocopy batch script was running. To do that, I'd suggest you use a known title or command invoked so that you can parse and identify the item to send to `taskkill`. Of course ending a robocopy operation before it is finished isn't usually my recommendation.

Comment: LotPings's advice worked perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

LotPings's advice: "taskkill /F /IM robocopy.exe" worked perfect.
Thank you

Comment: For me it "worked perfect" (reported successful kill) until I saw it still sitting in processes list, and still blocking some other processes.